# Убрать _id у вложенного документа

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Работаю с MongoDB через mongoose. Создавая большие документы приходится делать в них вложенные объекты. Заметил, что mongoose создает у каждого саб-документа поле _id. Покопавшись в документации, стало понятно, что сделано это для поиска по массиву вложенных документов:

> Each subdocument has an _id by default. Mongoose document arrays have a special id method for searching a document array to find a document with a given _id. `const doc = parent.children.id(_id);`

Выглядит это следующим образом:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Поле _id создается у любого вложенного объекта по умолчанию. Можно как-то отключить автоматическое создание этого поля за ненадобностью (поиск в данных полях попросту не нужен)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Достаточно просто указать в схеме опцию `_id : false`:

```
export const scheduleSchema = new Schema({
    min_age: Number,
    max_age: Number,
    schedule: [{
        weekday: String,
        time: String
    }]
}, {_id : false})
```

Во вложенных объектах схемы _id так же создаваться не будет